# Ledger nano s unrecoverable - have ethereum private keys - How do I get this ETH?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, recovery, ledger-nano-s

Lost the 24 word recovery sheet, and the pin number...

I"ve resolved that the BTC is gone, but if I opened in myetherwallet - and produced private key and UPC code - I'm told I could get the ETH back.

What are the steps to doing this? Very scared to mess up, and no I'm not sending private keys to anyone.

Could I just log in and open via private key on myetherwallet? 
Or do I need to do this first? Restore the code in some way? : 
https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005197905

Please advise.

Tone

Answer (score 1):

Your private key and your 24 word recovery sheet contain the same information. If you have one, you have the other.

The connection between the two is defined in [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki).

Assuming you do not have access to your private key (because you do not have access to your 24 word recovery sheet), it seems you are a little out of luck.

If you do not remember your PIN number, do NOT try to guess it using the Ledger. If you guess incorrectly 3 times, it will wipe your Ledger Nano S, certainly locking you from your tokens.

Instead, your best bet may be to wait and see if there is some sort of exploit which becomes available to compromise the Ledger Nano S in the future, and use that compromise on your own ledger to retrieve the private key back.

You are now a Hodler.

Comment: So if I have the etherwallet private key which I do, then what would be my next step?  Sorry to be so scared of BIP39... I want to learn.

Comment: Is your myetherwallet private key attached to the same account which your leger nano s generated? If so, then you might even be able to get your bitcoin back... Starting with ethereum, my recommended way would be to install MetaMask, and use the `Import Account` feature using your private key.

Comment: Yes, it was all attached, and that's why I had locked this away.  I have metamask... then use private key?  In etherwallet or in metamask itself? Thanks so much!

Comment: Within MetaMask itself. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZKSIkMj). You might need to generate a new account before you can access this part of the UX.

Comment: No Metamask import didn't work.  I think I have to do something like this: https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005197905  but it seems PC only, and the online version seems risky.   Probably going to wait till I can get some hand holding from a friend.